# How to add other QT Versions such as ARM, x86, MIPS for use by the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, qt-creator

I added the Android NDK to QT Creator and it's showing an error stating "QT Versions for architectures arm, x86, mips are missing"

When clicking on "add" in the Build & run > QT version tab, it seems to be looking for a file.

Any ideas where to find the file?

Answer (score 0):

If I good understood, your QT version can not find qmake for armv7, mips ? If is true you need **toolchain** each provided qmake for concret architekture. Example for armv7 completly toolchain is from Angstrom. Then you must define device , say your qt path to cross compiler, and SysRoot then yor QtVersion is be actived and you can develop program for concret platform. Angstrom complet toolchain you can find here:

https://4fe835f16ae6b3c2724bb430809c585acf3bdc3c.googledrive.com/host/0B3Z340LOBulvMG5NRmNlZEppSEE/